# Why nav bar doesn't respond on hovering

Tags: html, css

When I hover "company" my navigation bar is not responding (it should have show sub-menu when it's hovered), can somebody please help me out?
I tried many things but it just doesn't work.
So that's why I am asking for your help.

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bobo Web</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="img/logo.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="topbar">
      <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
      <p> Whatsapp: +86-15381188302 </p>
      <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <p> Beogard Serbija, 500000</p>
      <div class="icone">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-youtube-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <img src="img/logo.png">
      <input type="search" placeholder="Search ...">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">company  <span class="chevron bottom"></span></a></li>
        <div class="sub-menu-1">     //This submenu doesn't show when it's hovered
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Certificate</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">R & D Teams</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inovation</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <li><a href="">products <span class="chevron bottom"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="">knowledge <span class="chevron bottom"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="">online store <span class="chevron bottom"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="">contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <img src="img/pozadina.png">
    <p id="p1"> About our compnay</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
*{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

.topbar{
  background-color: #1fa9e5;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.top-bar * {
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
.topbar p{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 0;
}
.fa-phone, .fa-map-marker, .fa-facebook-square,.fa-twitter-square,.fa-youtube-square{
    color: white;
}
.icone{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.icone i{
  padding-top : 6px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

nav{
  width: 100%;
  height: 95px;
}
nav ul{
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 40px 40px;

}
nav ul li a{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
nav ul li:hover{
  background: #e0f8f6;
}
nav img{
  position: absolute;
  height: 70px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.chevron {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.25em 0.25em 0 0;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0.45em;
    left: 0.15em;
    position: relative;
    top: 0.15em;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 0.45em;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
#p1{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 80px;
}
nav input{
  float: right;
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
.sub-menu-1{
  display: none;
}
.nav ul li:hover .sub-menu-1{   //Not working at all
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  background: yellow;
  margin-top:  15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector line for current HTML should be:

```
nav ul li:hover + .sub-menu-1 {   /*Not working at all*/
```

Problems:

1. `<nav>` doesn't have a class of `nav`, so it should be `nav` instead of `.nav`
2. `.sub-menu-1` is a sibling, not a child so you should use `+`( [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator))
3. `//` is not valid CSS comment syntax, it can break compilation of that line
4. `.sub-menu-1` is a `<div>` which is direct child of `<ul>`, this is invalid HTML, it should be an `<li>` or within an `<li>`

```css
*{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

.topbar{
  background-color: #1fa9e5;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.top-bar * {
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
.topbar p{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 0;
}
.fa-phone, .fa-map-marker, .fa-facebook-square,.fa-twitter-square,.fa-youtube-square{
    color: white;
}
.icone{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.icone i{
  padding-top : 6px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

nav{
  width: 100%;
  height: 95px;
}
nav ul{
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 40px 40px;

}
nav ul li a{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
nav ul li:hover{
  background: #e0f8f6;
}
nav img{
  position: absolute;
  height: 70px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.chevron {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.25em 0.25em 0 0;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0.45em;
    left: 0.15em;
    position: relative;
    top: 0.15em;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 0.45em;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
#p1{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 80px;
}
nav input{
  float: right;
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
.sub-menu-1{
  display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover + .sub-menu-1 {   /*Not working at all*/
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
  margin-top:  15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bobo Web</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="img/logo.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="topbar">
      <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
      <p> Whatsapp: +86-15381188302 </p>
      <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <p> Beogard Serbija, 500000</p>
      <div class="icone">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-youtube-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <img src="img/logo.png">
      <input type="search" placeholder="Search ...">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">home</a></li>
        <li class="parent"><a href="">company  <span class="chevron bottom"></span></a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-1">     //This submenu doesn't show when it's hovered
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Certificate</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">R & D Teams</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inovation</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">products <span class="chevron bottom"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="">knowledge <span class="chevron bottom"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="">online store <span class="chevron bottom"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="">contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <img src="img/pozadina.png">
    <p id="p1"> About our compnay</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tired with plus sign, it's no working either.

Comment: @L.Krapic it's working in the above demo. Hover "company"

Comment: Thanks, it actually works,  I just had a syntax error as well.